# Why on some Linux systems, does the root filesystem appear as /dev/root instead of /dev/<real device node>in mtab?

Tags: linux, root-filesystem

I've seen on various Linux systems where instead of the real device node (for example: `/dev/sda1`), the root device appears as `/dev/root`, or instead of the real filesystem, `mtab` says it is a filesystem called `rootfs` (which appears as a real filesystem in `/proc/filesystems`, but doesn't have code in `<linux-kernel-source-tree>/fs`). Various utilities have been made to use certain attributes to determine the real root device node (such as rdev, and the Chromium OS rootdev). I can find no logical explanation to this other than reading somewhere that very-small embedded devices don't always have to have a `/dev` device node for their root device. (Is this true, and if so, is that the answer to my question?) Why does mtab sometimes say `/dev/root` (and I think I might have seen it say `rootdev` once) instead of the real device node, and how can I make it always say the real device node? The kernel first mounts the root device following the `root` parameter in the cmdline, then `init/systemd` re-mounts it according to the `fstab`, correct? <strike>If so, then I presume `init` maintains `mtab`. If my theory is correct, how can I make `init` write the real root device node to `mtab`?</strike> I noticed that `/etc/mtab` is actually a symbolic link to `/proc/mounts`, which would mean `mtab` is maintained by the kernel. So how do I configure/patch a kernel to, instead of saying the root devices node path is `/dev/root`, have `mtab` contain the real device node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is generally an artifact of using an initramfs.

From the kernel documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt)

> ### What is rootfs?
>
> Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs (or tmpfs, if that's enabled),
>   which is always present in 2.6 systems.  You can't unmount rootfs for
>   approximately the same reason you can't kill the init process; rather
>   than having special code to check for and handle an empty list, it's
>   smaller and simpler for the kernel to just make sure certain lists
>   can't become empty.
>
> Most systems just mount another filesystem over rootfs and ignore it. 
>   The amount of space an empty instance of ramfs takes up is tiny.

Thus `rootfs` is the root filesystem that was created for the initramfs, and can't be unmounted.

In regards to `/dev/root`, I'm less certain on this, but if I recall correctly `/dev/root` is created when using an initrd (not the same as an initramfs).

Comment: `mount` gives `rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)` for initrd and `/dev/root on / type ext2 (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr)` for ext2 hard disk [with this setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8217e5508782827320209644dcbaf9a6b3141724#qemu-buildroot-setup-getting-started).

Comment: `/dev/root` is used by some implementations of initramfs but not others - in these cases it is not due to the kernel.  When *not* using an initramfs, it seems to be a placeholder value used by the kernel.  (Maybe it could be removed in some later kernel version though).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310046/how-does-linux-kernel-create-dev-root-initramfs-query

Answer (score 4):

Gentoo has a patch that does exactly this (ensures the real root device is shown). You can find it here: https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/1/31/574

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, `/dev/root`, if present, is a symlink to the actual device created at boot time.

You either use `readlink /dev/root` or `cat /proc/cmdline` to see the `root` parameter of the booted kernel, and thus find out the real device behind it.

From man `dracut(8)`

> However, to continue with a successful boot, the objective is to
>   locate
>              your root volume and create a symlink /dev/root which points to
>              the file system.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if  `/dev/root` is an artefact of RedHat based distributions.

Comment: Well, my Debian 8 doesn't have `/dev/root/`. On an old CentOS it seems to be an actual device node instead of a symlink.

Comment: Well, [OpenEmbedded's `base-files` recipe's `fstab`](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/base-files/base-files/fstab) mentions `/dev/root`, so it isn't just distros originating from Red Hat that are using it.