# Disk space disappeared

Tags: hard-disk, fdisk

`cd / && du -sh .` told me that the filesystem used 2.1G spaces of disk:

```
root@ubuntu:/# cd / &&  du -sh .
du: cannot access './proc/3874/task/3874/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/3874/task/3874/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/3874/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/3874/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
2.1G    .
```

However, `df -h` told me that all spaces had been used:

```
root@ubuntu:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.2G  6.8G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G   17M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Here is the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 7.4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1       2048 15523839 15521792  7.4G 83 Linux
```

I don't why I have `6.8G` spaces used, also, I don't know why `df -h` showed me the `/dev/root` instead of `/dev/mmcblk1p1`. `ls /dev/root` even showed me `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: You could be facing an issues with inodes (possibly too many small files). Therefore add the -i flag to df and du. Also use the --max-depth flag with du to delve further and further into your file system file space usage

Comment: You also could have some deleted files still using disk space. `sudo lsof | grep deleted'  will show something if that's the case

Comment: I would guess either deleted file hold by a process, or a corrupt SD card. for former case a mere reboot will do, for later case, if possible mount it physically on another device and issue a `fsck`.

Comment: You don't want to include `/proc`.  Use `du -xsh` (although it will not give a larger result :-).

Comment: `/dev/root` is mysterious to the best of us :-), but you don't need to worry about it. It is genuinely a representation of `/dev/mmcblk1p1`, there is nothing evil going on there. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295060/why-on-some-linux-systems-does-the-root-filesystem-appear-as-dev-root-instead